# What if the package imported in go mod is deleted?

Tags: go

My team use some open source libraries on Github, and they are worried about github packages being deleted, such as for political reasons.

So we use both go mod and vendor, use vendor to cache code.(if no vendor, CI/CD will download/build failed when library has been deleted.)

I don't want to keep the vendor, but there is no way to avoid the library being deleted.

Comment: You can use go mod vendor to have the source code of those packages in your vendor folder.

Comment: You can fork all libraries to be sure you have a working copy.

Comment: @TheFool Already done, we use both go mod and go vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Golang is a compiled program and you don't need to check the version of the imported package. When you download the package for the first time it will be cached in your system. and until you change the version of the package it will use the latest cache.

When the repository is deleted, your go mod file cant find the repository and it says not found. so you need to change it or replace it.

The first solution I can say now is you can fork the main repository and use the forked repository in your `go.mod` file.

but I think you are strict about this.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me it's cached in system, so cached in vendor is duplicate.
Keep the vendor folder is not necessary, and I can restore repository from system.